# How to link a dynamic library in QtCreator use qmake and MinGW32?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use hiredis and libevent in my project, I downloaded their source code and compiled them with CmakeGUI and MinGW32. Then i got the header files and those library files.

- libevent.a
- libevent.dll
- libevent.dll.a
- libevent_core.a
- libevent_core.dll
- libevent_core.dll.a
- libevent_extra.a
- libevent_extra.dll
- libevent_extra.dll.a
- libhiredis.dll
- libhiredis.dll.a

Then I wrote some test programs to use these libraries, but could not link successfully
The error looks like this:

```
error: undefined reference to `redisConnect'
```

here is my pro file and code.

```sh
#my pro file
#hiredis
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include/hiredis
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -llibhiredis.dll

#event2
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include/libevent
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -llibevent.dll
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -llibevent_core.dll
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -llibevent_extra.dll
```

```cpp
#include "hiredis.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    redisContext *asd = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
}
```

This is the compile output

```
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o release\Test.exe release/main.o
release/mainwindow.o release/moc_mainwindow.o 
-LC:\Users\VC\Desktop\Test\lib C:\Users\VC\Desktop\Test\lib\libhiredis.dll.a 
C:\Users\VC\Desktop\Test\lib\libevent.dll.a 
C:\Users\VC\Desktop\Test\lib\libevent_core.dll.a 
C:\Users\VC\Desktop\Test\lib\libevent_extra.dll.a 
D:\Work\env\cpp\Qt\5.12.9\mingw73_32\lib\libQt5Widgets.a 
D:\Work\env\cpp\Qt\5.12.9\mingw73_32\lib\libQt5Gui.a 
D:\Work\env\cpp\Qt\5.12.9\mingw73_32\lib\libQt5Core.a 
-lmingw32 D:\Work\env\cpp\Qt\5.12.9\mingw73_32\lib\libqtmain.a
-LC:\openssl\lib -LC:\Utils\my_sql\mysql-5.6.11-win32\lib 
-LC:\Utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib -lshell32 

release/mainwindow.o:mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x2c9): undefined reference to `redisConnect'
```

I tried two different libraries(libevent and hiredis) and got similar results, what am I doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: Try giving full path instead of this "LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -llibevent.dll" try giving like this
"LIBS += D:\lib\libevent.dll" also you can try removing dll from end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once set a 64-bit version of MinGW in environment variables, but I forgot
When I changed it to the 32-bit MinGW path, the compilation was successful and the dynamic library can be used

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the .dll, just give the name of the lib, I mean include the lib like this :

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include/hiredis
INCLUDEPATH += -L$$PWD/lib
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -llibhiredis
```

Then clean the project and run qmake.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried this, but the error is same. QtCreator will exec the same cmd like this   "g++ -LC:\Users\VC\Desktop\Test\lib\libhiredis.dll.a"    Whether with ".dll" or not.

Comment: Could you try to add the lib folder to your include path doing : `INCLUDEPATH += -L$$PWD/lib`

Comment: I will try. but in output “-LC:\Users\VC\Desktop\Test\lib”. it looks like the path has been inserted

Comment: @VanChun maybe I wasn't clear, I tried to edit my answer